# Replace a string with regex java

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace a sw version from a string like this: " XSYS: 3.5.0 " with something like this: " XSYS: 3.10.0 ". Only that i want a method that uses regex that can change whatever is after "XSYS: " , whether the are xx.yy.zz or x.yyy.zz characters after that or combinations like these. It has to be something generic, so that if the version will become eventualy 5.100.23 (it's just an example) it will keep working. I don't know if I was right in phrasing.

Comment: What have you tried in order to accomplish this?

Comment: You already have the technology, what is not working with your latest tentative ?

Comment: You can use https://regex101.com/ to test your RegEx

Comment: Will the string always contain just "XSYS:` followed by a version number?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at this site, as it helped me understand regex better :https://regex101.com/
else if a piece of code is what you want, please consider that i didn't test it :

```
String regex = "^XSYS: \\d{1,3}.\\d{1,3}.\\d{1,3}$"
Boolean matches = yourString.matches(regex);
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: thank you, after consulting the java documentation on regex i found that \\d+ fixed my problem.